# Get first and last name on Windows with Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm have problems with get the first name and last name with electron and node js, i have the username, but i need first name and last name.

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xnQX.jpg)

I tried:

```
   const username = require('username');
   const os = require ('os');
   const computerName = os.hostname();
   const fullname = require('fullname');

   console.log(os.userInfo());


   // Console:
   //{ uid: -1,
   //  gid: -1,
   //  username: 'mauroh',
   //  homedir: 'C:\\Users\\mauroh',
   //  shell: null 
   //}

   console.log("computerName: ", computerName);
   console.log("username: " , username());

   // Console:
   // computerName: DEV
   // username: mauroh

   fullname().then(name => {
    console.log(name);
   });

   // Console:
   // mauroh
```

Is there any way to get the first and last name? or profile name with electron or node js ?

Example: `Mauro HUC`

*Note: This app is only for windows.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it,

1. I am using the [username package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/username)  to obtain the logged-in user.

```
async getUsername() {
  return await username();
}
```

2. Then in node js and electron you can use the child processes, [child_process docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).
3. When you perform the command `net user <username>` or `net user <username> / domain` you get all the user information, among all the information is the full name, also the name can be empty.

```
const child = require('child_process');
let exec = child.exec;

// And make a function for do command

function execute(command, callback){
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){ 
      let result = null;

      if(!error){

        var splitted = stdout.split("\n");    
        var username = '';
        var fullname = '';

        for(var i=0; i < splitted.length; i++){
          if(splitted[i].search("User name") != -1){
            splitted[i] = splitted[i].replace('User name',' ');
            splitted[i] = splitted[i].trim();
            username = splitted[i];
          }else if(splitted[i].search("Full Name") != -1){
            splitted[i] = splitted[i].replace('Full Name',' ');
            splitted[i] = splitted[i].trim();
            fullname = splitted[i];
          }
        }

        let data = {
          username: (username) ? username.toLowerCase() : null,
          fullname: (fullname) ? fullname: null
        }

        result = data;
      } else{
        result = null;
      }
      callback(result); 
    });
  };
```

This way you can get the user's full name.

Answer (score 0):

The "fullname" module does in some cases not return the name as it can't be found. This is clearly stated in the GitHub repository for the module.